# Create additional login form based on zfcuser or some other module

Tags: zend-framework2

I have login form on frontend (route: mysite/front). It is based on zfcuser module. I want to add the same for backend (route: mysite/admin), the only difference -- it will use another table in DB. How can I do this?

Comment: by the way iv forgot to mention that you have to create another module for admin ... for example YourAdminModule and that array into config ... not works for same module as your normal login works in it.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in module installation read-me you can provide the entity for zfc user by this array in your module config :

```
'zfcuser' => array(
        // telling ZfcUser to use our own class
        'user_entity_class'       => 'Falcon\Entity\User',
        // telling ZfcUserDoctrineORM to skip the entities it defines
        'enable_default_entities' => false,
    ),
```

so change **Falcon\Entity\User**  *(falcon is the name of my development module, ignore it :) )*  to what ever table/entity you want to authenticate with 
have fun

Comment: by the way iv forgot to mention that you have to create another module for admin ... for example YourAdminModule and that array into config ... not works for same module as your normal login works in it.

Comment: Should I add some other code from zfcuser to the new admin module?

Comment: no just this ... are you using bjyauthorize module too?  also plz +1 answer if its helpfull

Comment: I created new simple module for admin (zfcadmin) and added zfcuser with params to its configuration. But I cannot see additional login form anywhere..

Comment: The problem is that I want to use 2 login forms. 1 Should be on mysite/front/login action, second on mysite/backend/login

Comment: iv forgot to mention that ... your approach is completely wrong ... you have separate admin and user access by ACL or Bjyauthorize not separate login !

Comment: But why cannot I use different logins? I want to store admin and user data in different tables, want to make different admin and front areas.